# React native iOS release build crash

Tags: react-native

I've just upgraded to RN 0.49.3 and got the follow crash when build as release on iOS 11

> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'r.default.PropTypes.bool')

I took almost 2 days to figure out what problem but still stuck at this
Any one can help me?

Comment: Try to upgrade your React version: `npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.13`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by given information, you probably use `PropTypes` from `react` package, do you? `PropTypes` has been removed from there and were moved to separated [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). I hope my assumption is correct and will help you to fix your problem.